# Changing error highlight color used by syntastic

Tags: vim, syntastic

How can the highlight color used by vim syntastic to mark the errors/warnings in code be changed. The error highlighting is enabled by default and can be changed using 
`g:syntastic_enable_highlighting` variable.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30501271/1356754

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` *after* the last `colorscheme` line:

```
hi SpellBad ctermfg=www ctermbg=xxx guifg=#yyyyyy guibg=#zzzzzz
hi SpellCap ctermfg=www ctermbg=xxx guifg=#yyyyyy guibg=#zzzzzz
```

with `www`/`xxx` three digit colors taken from [this palette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) and `#yyyyyy`/`#zzzzzz` whatever hexadecimal color you want.

You can also edit the relevant lines in your colorscheme.

Comment: Oops. The perils of copy/pasting.

Answer (score 12):

The Syntastic plugin defines two highlight groups:

```
highlight link SyntasticError SpellBad
highlight link SyntasticWarning SpellCap
```

You should be able to override this by putting similar lines in your config after Syntastic is loaded using different highlight groups from `:highlight`.

Comment: Thanks! I just missed out `SyntasticError` and `SyntasticWarning`. In the doc it only mentions `SyntasticErrorSymbol` and `SyntasticErrorLine` (same for warnings)