# Changing color of vim syntastic error window

Tags: vim, syntastic

I have installed syntastic on VIM to help me show errors in PHP code however with the current colorscheme/setting I have to following colors:
[image: error line]

As you can see it's very hard to read, I wonder if there is a way to change the color if this error window specifically.

Comment: To change the Vim Syntastic location list background color you can edit `ctermbg` in  `highlight QuickFixLine ctermfg=none ctermbg=none cterm=none`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is only for the current selected item in the quickfix window, that's the `Search` highlight group on top of the normal quickfix highlighting. You then have to change either one; the `Search` group will affect search results in other windows, too.

If this is other / special Syntastic highlighting, you best look through all groups in the `:hi` output to find the bad one.

#### Overriding

Unless you want to completely switch your colorscheme, you can adapt individual highlight groups via `:highlight` commands *after* the `:colorscheme` command in your `~/.vimrc`. Either `:hi link` to another predefined group, or provide your own `ctermfg=... guifg=...` etc. color definitions, as described by `:help highlight-args`.

Comment: The :hi command helped me a lot to identify the problem, it was indeed the Search group. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Syntastic doesn't change (nor cares about) highlighting of the error window.  It's a plain `quickfix` window, with filetype `qf`.  Looking at `syntax/qf.vim`, the default highlighting is this:

```viml
syn match   qfFileName      "^[^|]*" nextgroup=qfSeparator
syn match   qfSeparator     "|" nextgroup=qfLineNr contained
syn match   qfLineNr        "[^|]*" contained contains=qfError
syn match   qfError         "error" contained

hi def link qfFileName      Directory
hi def link qfLineNr        LineNr
hi def link qfError         Error
```

Thus, if you see the `quickfix` window in different colours than the main text, it's because your colour scheme has specifically intended it to look that way.  You can override highlighting for `qfFileName`, `qfSeparator`, `qfLineNr`, and `qfError` to make it more readable, but the better solution IMO would be to use a less broken colour scheme.

**Edit:** Vim 8.0.641 and later has `QuickFixLine`.

Comment: Changing to another scheme didn't work I still see the same color

Comment: @Martijn Smidt: Well something (presumably a plugin) does set it that way.  That isn't the default colour.

Comment: @Martijn Smidt: That said, it could be the `Search` group, as pointed out above by @Ingo Karkat.

Comment: @jamieyoung `QuickFixLine` was added in Vim 8.0.641 (13th June 2017).